# How to write query statement in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

Can anyone guide me for writing sql statement in laravel.

**Here my raw sql statement**

```
SELECT H.pos_sales_code,
       customer.customer_group,
       H.customer_id,
       customer.NAME          AS customer,
       customer.phone,
       customer.email,
       customer.referral_type AS referral,
       H.created_at           AS first_visit,
       pos_sales_product.product_name
FROM   pos_sales H
       INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_id,
                          Min(created_at) AS first_visit
                   FROM   pos_sales
                   GROUP  BY customer_id) X
               ON H.customer_id = X.customer_id
                  AND H.created_at = X.first_visit
       LEFT JOIN customer
              ON customer.id = H.customer_id
       LEFT JOIN pos_sales_product
              ON H.pos_sales_code = pos_sales_product.pos_sales_code
```

How to write this query in laravel. Thanks in advance for all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query using laravel query builder should look something along:

```
$results = select(
          DB::raw("
                    pos_sales_code,
                    customer.customer_group,
                    customer_id,
                    customer.name,
                    customer.phone,
                    customer.email,
                    customer.referral_type AS referral,
                    pos_sales.created_at  AS first_visit,
                    pos_sales_product.product_name
                    "))
            ->join(DB::raw('SELECT customer_id, Min(created_at) AS first_visit
                           FROM   pos_sales
                           GROUP  BY customer_id) X'), function($join){

                   $join->on('post_sales.customer_id', '=', 'first_visit'));
                   $join->on('post_sales.created_at', '=',  'first_visit'));
                   })

            ->leftJoin('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'pos_sales.customer_id')
            ->leftJoin('post_sales_product', 'pos_sales.pos_sales_code', '=', 'pos_sales_product.pos_sales_code')

            ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I did something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the raw expressions of the documentation? 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions